# Simplex Solver - is it possible to enforce maximum number of non-zero weights?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I have a problem which I am trying to solve using a simplex solver (but I am happy to use any approach that works).

$$
a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + ... + a_n x_n= TotalCost
$$
Where $a_i$ are constant inputs and $x_i$ are the weights that I am optimizing.

I have a constraint that the sum of weights needs to add up to one
$$
\sum^n_{i=1} x_i = 1
$$

I wish to have the largest possible number of non-zero weights. However, some weights will be zero (because they have a very high cost). There are solutions to this (such as [this Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080339/linear-programming-algorithm-that-minimizes-number-of-non-zero-variables)). However, this doesn't seem to work with my constraint that the weights always sum to one.

How to impose sparsity (or the opposite) in this case?

--- Added later ---

Take for example $n=4$
$$ a = (0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0)$$
The lowest cost solution is $x = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ but I would like to biase the solution such that $x = (0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0)$ becomes optimal.

My first instinct would be to add a term of the form 
$$
\lambda \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2
$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant (i.e. something aking to a $L_2$ regularization) but that is no longer linear.

One can add an $ \alpha \ z$ term, where $ z  \ge x_i \ \forall \ i$ but such a constraint seems to either do nothing (when $\alpha$ is too small) or force all $x_i$ that are non-zero to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- $0 < a_1 \le \cdots \le a_n$.$\\[2pt]$

  The weights $x_1,...,x_n$ are required to be nonnegative.

The objective is to minimize the total cost
$$C=a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n$$
subject to
$$x_1 + \cdots + x_n=1$$
but also, you want to impose to some additional constraints . . .

- As many of $x_1,...,x_n$ are nonzero as possible.$\\[4pt]$

  If $a_k < a_{k+1}$, then $x_k > x_{k+1}$.

As a proposed solution, you could add the constraints
$$x_k \ge \left({\small{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}}}\right)x_{k+1}$$
for $1\le k \le n-1$, together with the constraint 
$$x_n \ge d$$
for some fixed positive constant $d$.

Answer (score 1):

You could add extra binary variables $y_i$ that take value $0$ when $x_i=0$ and penalize $1-y_i$ in the objective function:

Add the following constraint, where $\varepsilon$ is a small constant $<1$:
$$
x_i\ge \varepsilon \;y_i\\
y_i \in \{0,1\}
$$

Then minimize the following term in the cost function, where $p$ is another constant (the penalty):
$$
p\sum_{i}(1- y_i)$$

When $x_i>\varepsilon$, $y_i=1$ and no penalty is accounted for in the objective function. When $x_i=0$, $y_i=0$ and the cost function is penalized. The difficulty may be in finding the best value for $\varepsilon$.